# Excel - Using max, if & and together

Tags: excel, if-statement, max

I'm trying to use an AND operator inside MAX and IF functions and am having trouble.  I want to find the maximum value from column C where both are true:

- column A = $D$1
- the max only considers the top 80% of the values in column B

So in the example below, the answer would be 7, since of the rows with column A = "foo" and the top 80% of column B which are 3,4,5,6 the max value is 7.

I have two components working:

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$12=$D$1,$C$1:$C$12))
```

returns 12

```
=MAX(IF(B1:B12>PERCENTILE(B1:B12,0.2),C1:C12))
```

returns 8

If I put them together like this it returns 0 (even with ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=MAX(IF(AND($A$1:$A$12=$D$1,B1:B12>PERCENTILE(B1:B12,0.2)),C1:C12))
```

The solution with both AND clauses should be 7

Can anyone help with this?

[image]

Comment: The **AND()** function does not work well with array formulas...............find an alternative................

Comment: Hint: either multiply the two booleans together or nest the ifs

Answer (score 0):

please modify array formula to:
    =MAX(IF(A1:A12=$D$1,IF(B1:B12>PERCENTILE(B1:B12,0.2),C1:C12)))
end with ctrl+shift+enter

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the booleans together did the trick:

```
=MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$12=$D$1)*(B1:B12>PERCENTILE(B1:B12,0.2)),C1:C12))
```

I don't know why multiplying works but AND doesn't.  God I hate Excel.